# Invariant distributions: Applications in the real World

Tags: probability-distributions, markov-chains, markov-process, neural-networks

I'm studying about invariant distributions for Markov processes; say in the context of dynamics of Random Neural Networks (biological Networks).

I can't fully understand what does an invariant distribution say about the actual phisical phenomenon ?

From what I understand, we know that the distribution  of the process will tend to the invariant distribution, so after "a while" said distribution and the invariant one should be alike...?

Answer (score 0):

As an example: Monte Carlo Markov chain: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo